# what we call the network with which we make phone calls?

Tags: meaning

It is always confusing to me what to call the network with which we make phone calls.

If mobile network regards to accessing internet with cellular data, then what network it is called to make phone calls?

Comment: Aka *landlines*

Comment: The mobile phone network does not communicate *via* the internet, but it can access it. It is not required when making a phone call. See [Top 5 Cell Phone with No Internet Access in 2023](https://medium.com/the-isp-family/top-5-cell-phone-with-no-internet-access-in-2022-d832d0d861d9).

Comment: What specifically do you mean? Traditional wired/PSTN/landlines? Cellular? VoIP/internet telephony? Some or all of those? Is there a reason "telephone network" isn't precise enough? (Technically, both landlines and mobile voice telephony are being replaced by data networks using IP, so this may not be a problem for long.)

Comment: *POTS - plain old telephone system*? Use your favourite search engine to validate this suggestion if you care to.

Answer (score 5):

That is the **public switched telephone network (PSTN).** As [Wikipedia states:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_switched_telephone_network)

> The public switched telephone network (PSTN) is the aggregate of the world's telephone networks that are operated by national, regional, or local telephony operators. It provides infrastructure and services for public telecommunication. The network consists of telephone lines, fiber optic cables, microwave transmission links, cellular networks, communications satellites, and undersea telephone cables interconnected by switching centers, such as central offices, network tandems, and international gateways, which allow telephone users to communicate with each other.